# Adding MX record for Network Solutions email to Azure App Domain

Tags: azure, mx-record, network-solutions

I need to add an MX record into the app domain name purchased thru Azure portal.
The default form to add a record set adds the .domainname after the mx record name.

The problem is that Network solutions says the MX record name must be mx1.netsolmail.net. (So in the portal it becomes mx1.netsolmail.net.domainname.com which is not what I need)

How can I add a record set in my DNS zone for that domain that doesn't end in the domain name?

Per the answer below I changed the settings to the following

[image: email portal settings]

Comment: Any process? Or if I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Nancy Xiong...No, both your answer and the sheet NetSol IT help sent me, have settings that are working. The azure portal is not letting me change the url for the mx record to what you or IT is suggesting since azure defaults it to ending in the (domainname).com

Comment: Not sure, Could you try to add the MX. CNAME records like the example in the reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [purchase a domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain#accept-terms-and-purchase) in the app service domain page, you actually have a new domain provider because App Service Domains use GoDaddy for domain registration and Azure DNS to host the domains.

If I am understanding it correctly, you would like to have an email delivered on your app domain name through Network Solutions but keep your domain through Azure. If so, you could refer to [this Mailbox Setup and configuration](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/setup-your-nsmail-to-work-with-non-nswebaddress/) to change/edit your MX and CNAME records in the Azure DNS zone.

Try to change the MX record to `inbound.[domain name].netsolmail.net` if your domain name was `janesbagels.com`, your Mail Server record would look like `inbound.janesbagels.com.netsolmail.net`. Also, you could change the other two CNAME records `mail` and `SMTP`.

For example,

[image]

Comment: ...see my update in the OP. I guess I have to wait now for a few hours to see if it takes. Well I didn't need a few hours...it's working now TYVM